# How to show all the tables from multiple databases

Tags: mysql

How to select all the tables from multiple databases in mySql..
I am doing the following steps but not able to achive the goal.

```
<?php
$a = "SHOW DATABASES";
$da = $wpdb->get_results($a);

foreach($da as $k){
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($k->Database);//prints all the available databases
echo '</pre>';
$nq = "USE $k->Database";//trying to select the individual database
$newda = $wpdb->get_results($nq);
$alld = "SELECT * FROM $k->Database";
$td = $wpdb->get_results($alld);
var_dump($td);//returns empty array
}
?>
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do

```
SELECT * FROM database
```

but you can do

```
USE DATEBASE;
SHOW TABLES;
```

or even better:

```
SHOW TABLES IN database
```

Comment: You should select @cherouvim's answer as the correct one!

Comment: This replies a different question that the original poster asked, it fixes syntax in his otherwise incorrect snippet so it just fixes the syntax of his incorrect command usage.

Answer (score 39):

Use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html):

```
select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables;
```

Answer (score 15):

Even better:

Show all tables in all databases (except internal mysql databases) in one SQL statement.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ( 'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql' )
```

Comment: Also exclude 'sys' in above: ... `NOT IN (..., 'mysql', 'sys');`

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this this:

```
mysql -e "select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables;" | \
    grep -Pv '^(sys|performance_schema|TABLE_SCHEMA|mysql|information_schema)' | \
    perl -pe 's/\s+/./' | \
    sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -e'select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables;'`

This depends on you having a file `~/.my.cnf` in place with the following contents:

```
[client]
user=ADMINUSER     ## set user, usually 'root' 
password=PASSWORD  ## set password
```